# Curl command to pass script line to get crumb value and execute my groovy script

Tags: jenkins, curl, csrf, jenkins-groovy

I have tried the below command to execute my groovy in jenkins script console to disable CSRF in v2.222.2.

CRUMB=$(curl -u "$userName" 'https://jenkins-testcrumb.origin-elr-core-nonprod.com/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)')

CRUMB_DISABLE=$(curl "$userName" "script=hudson.security.csrf.GlobalCrumbIssuerConfiguration.DISABLE_CSRF_PROTECTION = true" -H "$CRUMB"  https://jenkins-testcrumb.origin-elr-core-nonprod.com/scriptText)

Error:

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   462  100   462    0     0   1002      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1004
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: kvinod5; Unknown error
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: script=hudson.security.csrf.GlobalCrumbIssuerConfiguration.DISABLE_CSRF_PROTECTION = true; Unknown error
100    90    0    90    0     0    498      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   498

Can someone help me how to get the soultion??

Answer (score 1):

This will not work, use [Api Tokens](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) instead. The [Jenkins upgrade documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.222/) states:

> Set the system property `hudson.security.csrf.GlobalCrumbIssuerConfiguration.DISABLE_CSRF_PROTECTION` to true on startup to disable CSRF protection as well as the configuration UI for it. This is an unsupported option and may be removed in the future.

Which suggests that it already has to be set on startup, and can't be modified afterwards.

Furthermore there are several issues with what you are trying to achieve:

The error says that it can't find the host: `script=hudson.security.csrf.GlobalCrumbIssuerConfiguration.DISABLE_CSRF_PROTECTION = true;`, which points to your second `curl` call which is incorrect and should be:

```
$(curl -u "$userName" --data-urlencode "script=hudson.security.csrf.GlobalCrumbIssuerConfiguration.DISABLE_CSRF_PROTECTION = true" -H "$CRUMB" https://jenkins-testcrumb.origin-elr-core-nonprod.com/scriptText)
```

This call will still fail with an invalid crumb, since Crumbs are no longer accepted for scripts. You should use an [api token instead](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API).

Furthermore to set a property, you need to call `System.setProperty`, so your script should be:

```
"script=System.setProperty('hudson.security.csrf.GlobalCrumbIssuerConfiguration.DISABLE_CSRF_PROTECTION', 'true'"
```

But as mentioned before, the property is checked at startup time, so changing it later will not disable the Crumb system.